# emberjs Cannot clone an Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember 1.3.1 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.5. On creating new mode I get following error

> Assertion failed: Cannot clone an Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable

Following is my model code

> App.myModel = DS.Model.extend({
>        name   : DS.attr('string'),
>        age    : DS.attr('string')
>   });

In my create route model function

> return Em.Object.create({});

and finally on save I do following

> this.store.createRecord('property', this.get('model'));

Although despite the error, my backend service is called successfully and new model is saved.

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue which I fixed by doing the following:
In the model function of the route replace

```
return Em.Object.create({});
```

with

```
return this.store.createRecord('myModel');
```

and on save replace

```
this.store.createRecord('myModel', this.get('model'));
```

with

```
this.get('model').save();
```

Comment: I have tried your way. It works but it messes up the count of the number of users (I am using a user model) before you actually type in something. It is like you have a new empty record

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, in the scenario described by @acidleaf this is the solution offered by `Yehuda Katz` from the ember core team in this video:

[Off the Menu: Building a Client-Side With Ember and Rails - Yehuda Katz @ Rails Israel 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpQj9_qEUAc&list=PLXlUEQRo53e2Znzs0IF6ZpAA3rbj6quHM&feature=share&index=2)

In the route from which you're returning a list of resources to display (i.e the plural version of the resource StoriesRoute, PostsRoute, etc..), you'll returned a filtered list containing those which are not new:

```
model: function() {
  this.store.find('myModel');
  return this.store.filter('myModel',function(myModel){
    return !myModel.get('isNew');
  });
}
```

Comment: This should be the default behaviour for `store.find()`. If I wanted to include new models, then I should have to explicitly specify this.

Answer (score 3):

I am quite new to Ember and still trying to catch all problems caused when migrating to newer versions of Ember and Ember Data, but...

On one hand I think you have a mistake in last code block and that it should be:

```
this.store.createRecord('myModel', this.get('model'));
// myModel instead of property
```

But on the other hand I dont think this will be the problem :-/

anyway, try to look (and compare) to changes for Ember data here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md 
and also on this http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/createrecord-using-this-get-model-throws-an-error/3968 or similiar

hope it helps!

J.

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into this problem while learning Ember. The accepted answer works, but it first creates a new empty record in the store. This was not desired in my application as it displays the empty record in my view.

### My Solution

**Router**

```
App.ItemsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', {});
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
App.ItemsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.store.createRecord('item', {
        title: this.get('newTitle'),
        category: this.get('newCategory')
      }).save();
      this.transitionToRoute('items');
    }
  }
});
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
<ul class="list-group">
  {{#each}}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{title}} - {{category}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  {{outlet}}

  <li class="list-group-item">{{#link-to "items.new"}}Add{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items/new">
<li class="list-group-item">
  {{input class="form-control" value=newTitle placeholder="Title"}}
  {{input class="form-control" value=newCategory placeholder="Category"}}
  <button class="btn btn-default" {{action "save"}}>Save</button>
</li>
</script>
```