# Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an actual quite simple situation:
A route to add a new item. In the corresponding controller I pre define a mockup model of my new item:

```
item: Ember.Object.create({
                date: moment(),
                amountTotal: '',
                netto: '',
                //...more properties
}),
```

This needs to be an Ember-Object, not a plain js-Object, because otherwise other things would break.

When I try to safe that newly created item:

```
actions: {

    addItem: function() {
        let expense = this.store.createRecord('expense', this.get('item'));
    },
    //....
}
```

I get the error

> Assertion Failed: Cannot clone an Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable

**So my Question is:**
How *can I* create an Object that implements Ember.Copyable?
Or is there any way around this?

Yes, I've read the two [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344539/emberjs-cannot-clone-an-ember-object-that-does-not-implement-ember-copyable) about that.
The first gives a soulution where I would initially create a record in the store. This has the usual downsides to it (already populating in lists, ..).

I've also tried all ways I could think of to get around that like

```
item: Ember.Copyable.create({...})
// or 
let newItem = Ember.copy(this.get('item'));
let expense = this.store.createRecord('expense', newItem);
// and many more
```

*Finally:*
If there is a way to mock up a new Item (best with the definitions of the model) without creating a record, this would be the absolute best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try specifying default value for all the model properties, and then simply you don't need to provide argument for createRecord method.

Like the below, models/expense.js and you can simply say `this.store.createRecord('expense')` this will come up with all the default values.

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string',{ defaultValue: 'Sample Name'}),
  date: attr('date',{
    defaultValue(){
      //You can write some code and the return the result.            
      //if you have included moment, you can use that.
      return Date();
    }
  }),
  amount: attr('number',{ defaultValue: 10}),
  totalAmount: Ember.computed('amount',function(){
    return this.get('amount')*10;
  })    
});
```

2. Using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse like the below,

   `this.store.createRecord('expense', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.get('item'))))`

[Created twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e13d5f8f2f0ab046023b32ff228dcca6?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! The second trick indeed eliminates that error. __BUT__ it also breaks the Object, which loses the "belongsTo" relationships. So if there is not other way I'll have to create record to start with.

Comment: How about the first option ?.   Even if we implement copy method i believe which will do this kind JSON stringify..anyway what this will break if items is normal object. I dont get this point since i am not familiar with ember-data stuff..

Comment: The problem I'm having without the object beeing an Ember.Object lies in how some things need to be done in Ember. I still accept your answer!

Comment: With your constraints, if you believe there will be a solution for this, then you can keep this unanswered so that others can give their idea...